# UITextField selection error in Simulator iOS

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, response

i have new silly problem,i created **subview** with **three textfield** ,i connected all well, now when i **tap** to any **textfield** its working till third attempt after that its not working, now i am confused what the hell is happening , i add **textfild** throug **xib** .

```
 - (IBAction)weightMethod:(id)sender
   {

    centimeterTextField.placeholder = @"  Centimeters";
    self.centimeterTextField.delegate=self;
    self.centimeterTextField.tag=3;
    self.centimeterTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    self.centimeterTextField.clearsOnBeginEditing=YES;
    [ self.centimeterTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    ptextfield.placeholder = @"   Feet";
    self.ptextfield.delegate=self;
    self.ptextfield.tag=4;
    self.ptextfield.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    self.ptextfield.clearsOnBeginEditing=YES;
    [self.ptextfield setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    ptextfieldInches.placeholder = @"   Inches";
    self.ptextfieldInches.delegate=self;
    self.ptextfieldInches.tag=5;
    self.ptextfieldInches.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    [ptextfieldInches setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    self.ptextfieldInches.clearsOnBeginEditing=YES;
    [self.centimeterTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
    [self.ptextfieldInches setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
   [self.ptextfield setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];

 }
```

amazing fact is that when i am not connecting outlets to any of text field its working till u respond .

Comment: check all your IBOutlets connection just redo it that will do

Comment: your code is working for me..... Check out your outlets in xib again

Comment: its still not working for me, 3 times it work after that its not working, after 3rd time also key bord not resigning

Comment: please include the text field delegate methods implemented

Comment: @Youaregreat show code in your delegate methods.

Comment: what Rishi show code in your delegate methods its not clear to me

Comment: @Youaregreat You must have wrote some code in your TextField delegate methods. Include that code in your question.